# gls with ML not working so I can't find the best model

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme, biostatistics

My question is close to this one which wasn't really answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66571314/gls-with-arma-terms-not-working-for-one-combination-of-terms

I am running models to understand the trends highlighted by a Principal Component Analysis regarding variability in the morphology of some plants.
I have a set of quantitative (n=1, "PI", a percentage) and mostly qualitative (n=10, eg., Family, Genus, Species, leaf type) variables whose effect I would like to test on a quantitative variable "LMA" (a leaf thickness).

I initially used a GLM (because LMA data are neither normal nor homoskedastic) and on a reduced dataset because of a lot of lines with NAs for LMA.
In order to have a larger dataset, we supplemented LMA measurements with average values for some species (variable "Species") having n>5 LMA measurement. The variance of LMA is now highly heterogeneous and reduced for some of the species.

Thus, I switched to GLS to take into account this particularity with `weights = varIdent(form=\~1|Species)` and I made several models with `method = REML` to test the effect of the different variables (as some categorical variables were nested, I did not test them at the same time).

Today, I read several times that selecting the best fitting gls using AIC is only possible for gls made using ML (especially since not all my models have the same fixed effects).
A solution seems to be to make anova on the models updated in ML ... But ... it doesn't work for me ... (although I have no NAs in my dataset) ...

The problem is that depending on the models, the significant effects are different ... I have read that the best model is also the one that contains the most variables with a significant effect. Is this right? Should I just go back to this and choose my model based on this individual anovas?

I hope this post is quite clear and I sincerely thank you in advance!

-------

The dataset I use (all variables but "PI" are qualitative), I specified they were factors, there is no NAs.

```
x <- c("species_LMA", "Locality", "Family", 
    "Genus", "Species", "specimen_TCT", 
    "taxon_TCT", "combined_TCT", "cat_TCT", 
    "PI", "Pheno", "Growth_form")  
noNA4 <- subset(data2, complete.cases(data2[, 
                x])) # n = 561
```

Here are are the different models I made:

```
xm1a <- gls(species_LMA ~ -1 + Family + PI + 
    Locality + cat_TCT + Pheno , 
    weights = varIdent(form=~1|Species), 
    data=noNA4, na.action=na.omit)  
xm1b <- gls(species_LMA ~ -1 + Family + PI + 
    Locality + specimen_TCT + Pheno , 
    weights = varIdent(form=~1|Species), 
    data=noNA4, na.action=na.omit)  
xm1c <- gls(species_LMA ~ -1 + Family + PI + 
    Locality + combined_TCT + Pheno , 
    weights = varIdent(form=~1|Species), 
    data=noNA4, na.action=na.omit)
```

```
xm2a <- gls(species_LMA ~ -1 + Genus + PI + 
    Locality + cat_TCT + Pheno , 
    weights = varIdent(form=~1|Species), 
    data=noNA4, na.action=na.omit)  
xm2b <- gls(species_LMA ~ -1 + Genus + PI + 
    Locality + specimen_TCT + Pheno , 
    weights = varIdent(form=~1|Species), 
    data=noNA4, na.action=na.omit)     
xm2c <- gls(species_LMA ~ -1 + Genus + PI +  
    Locality + combined_TCT + Pheno , 
    weights = varIdent(form=~1|Species), 
    data=noNA4, na.action=na.omit)

xm3a <- gls(species_LMA ~ -1 + Species + PI + 
    Locality + cat_TCT + Pheno , 
    weights = varIdent(form=~1|Species), 
    data=noNA4, na.action=na.omit)    
#xm3b <- gls(species_LMA ~ -1 + Species + PI + 
    Locality + specimen_TCT + Pheno , 
    weights = varIdent(form=~1|Species), 
    data=noNA3, na.action=na.omit) 
# do not work for some reason ... correlation?`  
xm3c <- gls(species_LMA ~ -1 + Species + PI + 
    Locality + combined_TCT + Pheno , 
    weights = varIdent(form=~1|Species), 
    data=noNA4, na.action=na.omit)
```

Line to select the best model based on AIC (package MuMIn)

```
model.sel(xm1a, xm1b, xm1c, xm2a, xm2b, xm2c, 
          xm3a, xm3c) 

    Model selection table 
         cat_TCT Fml Lcl Phn     PI spc_TCT cmb_TCT Gns Spc df    logLik   AICc  delta weight
    xm3c               +   +  8.254               +       + 60 -2051.166 4237.2   0.00      1
    xm3a       +       +   +  8.604                       + 56 -2064.354 4253.6  16.37      0
    xm2b               +   + 10.380       +           +     52 -2085.641 4286.3  49.10      0
    xm2c               +   +  9.439               +   +     49 -2092.155 4292.1  54.84      0
    xm2a       +       +   + 10.510                   +     45 -2105.152 4308.5  71.26      0
    xm1b           +   +   +  2.933       +                 47 -2111.535 4326.0  88.79      0
    xm1c           +   +   +  5.425               +         44 -2115.838 4327.5  90.26      0
    xm1a       +   +   +   + 11.680                         40 -2138.920 4364.2 127.04      0
    Models ranked by AICc(x)
```

```
# best option are *3c* then 3a, 2b, 2c, 2a, 1c, 1b, 1a but AIC are highly similar  
# xm3c : LMA ~ Species + PI + Locality + combined_TCT + Pheno
```

but since we took species-mean LMA, it is quite logical ... if we consider the relation to species is biased because we used species mean values, then the best model would be xm2b: `LMA ~ Genus + PI + Locality + specimen_TCT + Pheno`

What I tried to update the model (here an example for two of them) to ML to evaluate their performance using AIC (and resulting error message).

```
anova(update(xm3c, . ~ ., method = "ML"), update(xm2b, . ~ ., method = "ML"))`

    Error in eigen(val, only.values = TRUE) : 
      infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

Example of anova results for 3 models. The problem is that depending on the models, the significant effects are different ...

```
    anova(xm1b) 
    Denom. DF: 531 
                 numDF   F-value p-value
    Family           9 2137401.7  <.0001
    PI               1       0.1  0.7331
    Locality         1     118.4  <.0001
    specimen_TCT    10       5.2  <.0001
    Pheno            1       0.1  0.7080
    
    > anova(xm2b) # nothing but Species is significant... marginal corr of PI... 
    Denom. DF: 526 
                 numDF   F-value p-value
    Genus           14 247220.46  <.0001
    PI               1      2.76  0.0970
    Locality         1      0.10  0.7500
    specimen_TCT    10      0.56  0.8456
    Pheno            1      0.41  0.5226
    
    anova(xm3c) # nothing but Species is 
                # significant
    Denom. DF: 518 
                 numDF   F-value p-value
    Species         25 195602.70  <.0001
    PI               1      2.12  0.1463
    Locality         1      0.18  0.6691
    combined_TCT     7      0.75  0.6304
    Pheno            1      0.17  0.6784
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I initially used a GLM (because LMA data are neither normal nor heteroskedastic [maybe you meant "homoskedastic"?])

That might not be necessary. The distributional issues have to do with errors around the model predictions, not the raw data.

> we supplemented LMA measurements with average values for some species

That's not typically a good way to deal with missing data. See Stef van Buuren's [Flexible Imputation of Missing Data](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/) for the advantages of creating multiple imputed data sets so that you have the best chance of avoiding bias while including the variance arising from filling in missing data.

> Example of anova results for 3 models. The problem is that depending on the models, the significant effects are different ...

Check the documentation for how `anova()` works with those model objects. It's possible that it uses a sequential Type I method so the [order of variables in the model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13241/28500) might affect the apparent "significance" of the individual predictors.

It's not clear why you are doing separate models for each of `cat_TCT`, `specimen_TCT` and `combined_TCT`. It's generally better to start with as many predictors in a model as reasonable without overfitting, even if some predictors are somewhat correlated. (If predictors are linearly dependent or close to that, you should choose a linearly-independent set.)

I don't know why you are having troubles with ML versus REML. [You can't compare AIC values among models having different fixed effects that are fit via REML](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/116770/28500). Work through one step at a time to see the source of the error, instead of combining updates with `anova()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Quickly: for the decision to do a GLM, yes, I meant "homoskedastic" and I had indeed tested the residuals of the models directly. For the variables "x_TCT", it was not possible to test them at the same time, because yes, they are nested. 
I used MICE and, since there is no problem with the variance any more, I could run a GLMs afterward and use the function "step"{Stats} to generate best model formula. 
You are right, it was Type-I anova so there is an effect of variable's order in the model formula on the results. I now use Anova type II, "Anova" {Car}.

Comment: @AgatheToumoulin glad to help. If this answers your question, please mark the answer as accepted. It can be dangerous to use stepwise model selection, however. Please read [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20836/28500) for discussion of the dangers. If parsimony of your model is more important than precision in making predictions, then some limited backward selection might be OK. See Frank Harrells's [course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) and [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/), in particular Chapter 4, for guidance.