# Generalized additive model: Variable & model selection

Tags: model-selection, regularization, aic, generalized-additive-model, reml

I know this type of question has been asked many times before, so I apologize for re-posting about it. I bring it up again because it's been taught in one of my courses of study and I want to make sure I'm learning the correct methods. I can't share the data, but this is the part of the code that I'm confused by:

```
M1 <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = "cr") + s(Year, bs ="cr") +  
        factor_A + factor_B, 
      method = "REML",
      select = TRUE,
      data = df)

M2 <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = "cr") + s(Year, bs ="cr") + 
            factor_A * factor_B,
          method = "REML",
          select = TRUE,
          data = df)

M3 <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = "cr", by = factor_B) + s(Year, bs ="cr") + 
            factor_A + factor_B,
          method = "REML",
          select = TRUE,
          data = df)

M4 <- gam(y ~ s(z, bs = "cr", by = factor_B) + s(Year, bs ="cr") + 
            factor_A + factor_B,
          method = "REML",
          select = TRUE,
          data = df)

M5 <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = "cr", by = factor_B) + s(Year, bs ="cr", by = factor_B) + 
            factor_A + factor_B,
          method = "REML",
          select = TRUE,
          data = df)

M6 <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = "cr") + s(z, bs = "cr") + s(Year, bs ="cr", by = factor_B) + 
            factor_A + factor_B,
          method = "REML",
          select = TRUE,
          data = df)

M7 <- gam(y ~ te(x, Year) + 
             factor_A + factor_B,
           method = "REML",
           select = TRUE,
           data = df)

M8 <- gam(y ~ s(x, by = fYear) + 
             fYear + factor_A + factor_B,
           method = "REML",
           select = TRUE,
           data = df)

M9 <- gam(y ~ s(Year, by = factor_B) + 
             factor_A + factor_B,
           method = "REML",
           select = TRUE,
           data = df)

AIC(M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8, M9)
```

y = continuous response, and x, z = continuous covariates.

GAM models specifically (not glm) fit by REML can be compared with AIC, so that seems fine. As I understand it though, models shouldn't be compared if they were fitted by REML and have different fixed effects. This seems to be the case with model M4 and M6 as they contain an extra `z` term. Also, `select` is set to `TRUE` in every model before being compared in AIC. I took this option to be a separate method of selection (not to be used in combination with the AIC method). `Select=TRUE` can only be used on a single (final) model AFTER using AIC, as a form of variable selection. Am I mistaken here? Thank you!

**References:**

Pedersen, E. J., Miller, D. L., Simpson, G. L., & Ross, N. (2019). Hierarchical generalized additive models in ecology: An introduction with mgcv. PeerJ, 7, e6876. https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.6876

Comment: Reading from an example (https://r.qcbs.ca/workshop08/pres-en/workshop08-pres-en.html#1), that looks like what I've seen on this site, when using AIC, select=FALSE, while adding in new terms is ok (Latitude, page 58)(?) This seems contradictory though as... "using likelihood-based methods (including AIC) to compare two models with different fixed effects that are fitted by REML will generally lead to nonsense." => https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116770/reml-or-ml-to-compare-two-mixed-effects-models-with-differing-fixed-effects-but

Comment: The try-multiple-model approach does not take model uncertainty into account, so confidence bands will be too narrow.  It would be better to use subject matter knowledge to posit a single flexible model, or at most 2-3 models.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When fitting multiple models you can use AIC, but you have to appreciate what metric the two models are being assessed on. With AIC, which is an approximation to the leave-one-out cross validation error, the metric by which you are comparing models is one of their predictive ability. Using this as your metric, you'd be adding/removing variables with a confidence level of ~0.16 (instead of the "usual" 0.05, not that this usual value is a good option).

Once you've chosen your model with AIC, you then have the problem that any inference you might do is messed up by all the model selection you did. This is the point @Frank Harrell makes in his comment. If you only care about prediction then you might not be doing any post-selection inference (looking at *p* values, plotting smooths with the credible intervals, etc), but if you are going to do that inference, selection via AIC for other type of stepwise selection) is going to mess things up until we have a good theory for post-selection inference (which is an active area of research; though I've not seen anything for GAMs as yet)

> `select=TRUE` can only be used on a single (final) model AFTER using AIC, as a form of variable selection. Am I mistaken here?

Yes; you are mistaken. One would use `select = TRUE` **instead** of doing model selection by AIC, largely because the consequences of doing the selection via extra shrinkage penalties can be accounted for in the model `summary()` output/tests, where is can't (yet) be accounted for if you have done AIC-based selection.

From the example code you show, it seems there is interest in testing if there are combinations of one or more smooth-by-smooth or smooth-by-factor interactions. Unless I was solely interested in creating a prediction tool, I  would not be comparing all those models via AIC.

Furthermore, it seems like the models are exploring different hypothesis about the temporal aspects of the data set; does the effect of `x` vary smoothly over the years? or does the effect of time (year) differ between levels of `factor_B`.

None of these seem like something I'd want to compare using AIC (unless I was purely trying to find a model for prediction).

Personally, if I thought there was an interaction between the two factor variables, I'd fit that interaction and then consider the estimates of the effect size of that interaction. I wouldn't decide to exclude the interaction on the basis of a *p*-value (and AIC selection is using *p* values, just with a confidence level of ~0.16 for terms differing by 1 DF), not least because that is a *very* strong statement that the interaction effect is 0, which is very unlikely.

The choice of smooth terms doesn't make sense to me; perhaps it does in the context of the scientific problem you are working on? The `s(z)` term only comes up in one of the models for example, why is that? It might just be that your instructor is getting you to do something that isn't "best practice" but to show you what can happen when you use those "not best-practice" techniques. I.e. to make a point pedagogically. Without more context on why those candidate models were chosen, it's hard to comment further.

As to your discoveries:

- The Workshop presentation you link to in the comments focuses too much (IMHO) on AIC as the selection metric.
- `select = TRUE` can be used with AIC, but using `select = TRUE` kind of renders the whole model-selection-by-AIC thing redundant as the extra penalties on the smooths are doing selection for you. That doesn't mean AIC computed on the model is wrong; you could still compare it with a model that didn't have the extra shrinkage applied for example.
- `select = TRUE` isn't only applicable when you have **one** model in mind. You might have two or a few well-selected models in mind and you can apply the extra shrinkage to all those models. But yes, it is typical that you have a *full* model (something that contains a well-thought-out selection of covariates/terms, not simply every variable you have in your data set.)
- The AIC that is used in mgcv is a special AIC that is suited to the situation where we have smoothness parameter selection going on. This AIC uses a special penalty term replacing the $2k$ penalty from common-or-garden AIC. I am not aware of similar results for BIC, so I would use BIC with care with GAMs.

Comment: Thanks Gavin for the thorough answer! Quick question, how would one do model selection for (say) two well-thought out models, both with the select=TRUE option made?

Comment: I went through my lecture notes again regarding why z was added and I have here that "x and z are morphometric variables and we wanted to know if z was a better predictor of y than x, and if z differed by factor_B."

Comment: I think it depends on what you are trying to achieve; if those well-thought-out models represented different hypotheses, I likely wouldn't do any selection at all; I'd just fit those models, estimating the relevant effects and them compare the models.  If I wasn't sure if any of the terms were needed in the respective models (though how did you come up with those models in the first place?), I'd use `select = TRUE` with `paraPen` for the parametric terms. If I was unsure about some terms, then using one of the shrinkage bases would allow something like `select = TRUE` but for selected smooths

Comment: Gotcha! Just to clarify, if I changed model M1 in my OP to have a linear x term, and called it M1b, would these two models qualify as a having different hypotheses or "different fixed effects"? Or are M4 and M6 the only ones with the different hypothesis and/or fixed effect b/c of the z term? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, to your 3rd point, what is the procedure for comparing two models with select=TRUE?

Comment: If I needed to compare them (and it's not clear to me why you need `x` **or** `z` - is nature really so discriminating that it is one or the other not some combination?), then I'd use AIC to assess prediction accuracy, model diagnostics to evaluate the model fit, and use ML and compare with `anova(m1, m2)`, accepting that the *p* values on the latter are only approximate (plus the other issues Simon mentions).

Comment: But I'm assuming those models are nested; the ideas behind the GLRT can be thought of testing two models, where in one of those models one or more parameters in the other model have been set to zero. If you're considering comparing `y~s(x)` with `y~s(z)` this way, I don't think the theory of GLRTs applies. If that's what you';re asking about, I would probably use AIC to compare how well each model fitted the data (in terms of prediction error). Plus model diagnostics. But I'm not sure I would *in practice* end up in this situation; if `x` and `z` describe different things...

Comment: ...I would probably include both in the model (so long as they weren't very strongly correlated) and let the model sort out the effects of `x` and `z`, so that I have only one model to test and consider. This would stop us from testing multiple models and facing the associated multiple testing problems for inference on the chosen model. Like I said, it's hard for me to think of a situation where it is *either* `x` or `z` affecting the response, except for a in a prediction/forecasting mode where leave-out predictive accuracy is the key metric, in which case I'd be using AIC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150760/discussion-between-nate-and-gavin-simpson).

Answer (score 1):

What I found:

1. `Select` should be `FALSE` when comparing with AIC
2. `Select=TRUE` ONLY when we have a single model in mind (instead of comparing many models with AIC)
3. All models being compared should be fit with `method=ML` when unpenalized fixed effects (parametric terms) are present (like [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/578023/comparing-log-likelihood-of-nested-gam-models-mgcv))
4. `Method=REML` is fine though for comparing "nested" GAM(M) models in AIC when all effects are fully penalized

Found a great tutorial on GAMs from Gavin [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ukfvd8akfco&t=4457s) which covers most of this.

Comment: Just because those authors *didn't* use `select = TRUE` when comparing models doesn't mean you shouldn't.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, is plotting and interpreting the effects of a single model fit with select=TRUE ok to do or is it also a form of post-selection inference?

Comment: It would still constitute post-selection inference, but if you look closely in the summary output the reference EDF for the test is set to the basis dimension for each smooth (9 by default for univariate smooths). Normally the reference EDF would be close to the `edf` but with `select = TRUE` we reflect our uncertainty by paying the full price of the basis size, despite applying shrinkage.  I think this reflects the fact that any function in the null space 1 basis is possible, and the shrinkage is to the Null hypothesis $\mathbf{H}_0: f_j(x_{ij}) = 0 \; \forall \; i$

Comment: You can think of `select` as being a bit like the Lasso but for smooths. With the Lasso, we could test the shrunken coefficients as if the selection hadn't happened, or use some new theory that accounts for selection. While we don't have the same kind of post selection inference theory that is being developed for a range of models including the Lasso, the paper by Marra and Wood (2012 IIRC) includes other work to show performance of the method, but I don't recall specifics about how the extra shrinkage affects inference on smooths: I only recall the results on the selection itself.